# The intervals $[-\infty,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,+\infty]$ are open in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ and Is it possible to write them as a countable union?

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

According to Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, the topology $\tau$ in $\overline{\mathbb R}$ consists of sets of the form $(a,b), [-\infty, a), (a, \infty]$ and any union of segments of this type, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

In light of this, can we say that the intervals $[-\infty, \infty)$, $(-\infty,+\infty]$ are open in $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$?

Is it possible to write them as a countable union?

For me the answers is yes, because $$[-\infty, +\infty)=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty[-\infty, n)$$ and $$(-\infty, +\infty]=\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-n, +\infty]$$ it's correct?

Comment: yes because $[-\infty ,\infty )=\bigcup_{a\in \mathbb R}[-\infty ,a)$.

Comment: @Surb, can we write it as a coutable union?

Comment: @NatMath $[-\infty, \infty) = \bigcup _{n \in \mathbb{N}} [-\infty, n)$ is ok

Comment: @Folpo13Thanks! And the other? How can I write the interval $(-\infty,+\infty]$ as something countable?

Comment: No need a countable union : any union (countable or not) of open sets is an open set...

Comment: @Surb yes you are right. But I would like to be able to write $(-\infty,+\infty]$as a countable union or intersection. it's possible?

Comment: $(-\infty,+\infty]=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}(-n,+\infty]$